# Can every Cauchy r.v be expressed as a fraction of two Normal r.v?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $Z$ be a random variable following the standard Cauchy distribution, $Z\sim C(0,1)$

Then the random variable
$$W=\frac{1+Z}{1-Z}$$
follows also a standard Cauchy distribution, $W\sim C(0,1)$

it's easy to check using the variable change formula where supposing
$$W=\varphi(Z)=\frac{1+Z}{1-Z}\implies Z=\varphi^{-1}(W)=\frac{1-W}{1+W}$$
And then calculating
$$f_W(w)=f_Z(\varphi^{-1}(w))\Bigg|\frac{d}{dw}\varphi^{-1}(w)\Bigg|$$

My approach is that since $Z\sim C(0,1)$ then I can assume

$$\exists X, \exists Y \text{  such that } X\sim \mathcal N(0,1), Y\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and
$$ Z=\frac{X}{Y}$$

Then we would get

$$W=\frac{1+Z}{1-Z}=\frac{1+\frac{X}{Y}}{1-\frac{X}{Y}}=\frac{\frac{X+Y}{Y}}{\frac{X-Y}{Y}}=\frac{X+Y}{X-Y} \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,identically distributed, and $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, $Y\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, we would have
$$X+Y\sim \mathcal N(0,2)\implies \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

Same thing for $X-Y$
$$\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$
From $(1)$ we can rewrite
$$ W=\frac{X+Y}{X-Y}=\frac{\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

And since $\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, then we conclude that
$$W\sim C(0,1)$$

My question here : Is it always true that every single Cauchy random variable can be expressed as a fraction of two Normally distributed random variables ? If so, is it the same case with all the other distributions which have the same case ?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_central_normal_ratio. Can you clarify your second question, what do you mean by "all other distributions which have the same case"?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I meant the distributions which also have a ratio or a sum relationship. Like the Poisson distribuion for example, I can assume that there's always a sequence of Binomial r.v's that converges to the Poisson r.v, right ?